# Python: ограничить создание экземпляра

Tags: python, ооп

Допустим, у меня есть класс Person:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name, surname, birth, death):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.birth = birth
        self.death = death
```

Экземпляры с одинаковыми именем и фамилией могут существовать только в том случае, если у них непересекаются даты рождения и смерти.
Например:

```
first_instance = Person(name='John', surname='Doe', birth='1980/01/01', death='2010/12/31')
second_instance = Person(name='John', surname='Doe', birth='2011/01/01', death='2060/12/31')
```

Такой вариант допустим. Но если пользователь введет следующий вариант, нужно поднять ошибку:

```
first_instance = Person(name='John', surname='Doe', birth='1980/01/01', death='2010/12/31')
second_instance = Person(name='John', surname='Doe', birth='2007/01/01', death='2060/12/31')
```

Как видите, *second_instance.birth < first_instance.death (2007/01/01 < 2010/12/31)*. Taкого быть не должно. Что-то мне подсказывает, что надо использовать `def __new__()`, но я не совсем понимаю как это реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

Я не очень знаю как это правильно делать в питоне (в каком методе нужно проверять и какое исключение нужно кидать), но вот так вроде работает:

```
class Person():
    person_list = []

    def __init__(self, name, surname, birth, death):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.birth = birth
        self.death = death

        for p in Person.person_list:
            if p.name == self.name and p.surname == self.surname and (p.birth <= self.birth <= p.death or self.birth <= p.birth <= self.death):
                raise ValueError(f'{self} имеет пересекающееся время жизни с {p}')
                 
        Person.person_list.append(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.surname} {self.birth}-{self.death}'

first_instance = Person(name='John', surname='Doe', birth='1980/01/01', death='2010/12/31')
second_instance = Person(name='John', surname='Doe', birth='2011/01/01', death='2060/12/31')
third_instance = Person(name='John', surname='Doe', birth='2007/01/01', death='2060/12/31')
```

На попытке создать третью персону будет выкидывать исключение:

```
ValueError: John Doe 2007/01/01-2060/12/31 имеет пересекающееся время жизни с John Doe 1980/01/01-2010/12/31
```

Comment: Благодарю, надо проверить, но ваш вариант делает смысл :)

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант. Словарь __created недоступен вне класса.

```
class Person:
    __created = []

    def __init__(self, name, surname, birth, death):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.birth = birth
        self.death = death
        self.__check_can_create()

    def __check_can_create(self):
        for p in self.__created:
            if all((p.death == self.death, p.name == self.name, p.surname == self.name, p.birth == self.birth)):
                raise ValueError('Can`t create person: Person already exists.')
        self.__created.append(self)


Person(1, 1, 1, 1)
Person(1, 1, 1, 2)
Person(1, 1, 1, 3)
Person(1, 2, 3, 1)
Person(1, 1, 1, 2)  # ValueError
```